# Как получить определённые элемент из ответа AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

есть AJAX запрос

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/news",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "html",
         data: "PAGEN_1="+i,
         success: function(data){
             // что здесь должно быть?
         }
});
```

В `data` попадает целая страница , то есть с тегом `<html>`, `<body>` и.т.д.
Как из `data` получить конкретный элемент или набор элементов с содержимым???
Например `<div class="myclass">`?

Comment: Например: `console.log(data);`

Comment: Вопрос - зачем вы возвращаете целую страницу и зачем из неё нужно получить какой-то элемент? Почему нельзя вернуть данные и на стороне клиента построить нужный элемент?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myclass= $(data).filter('.myclass').html();
```

Comment: Я так сделал, console.log(myclass) показывает undfined . Хотя элемент в ответе есть 100%

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос исходным кодом страницы, то что вам приходит в data